# Tool for creating DBManager classes in Java?

Tags: java, sql

Is there a tool for creating DBManager class for simple databases in SQL? I want to use it along with netbeans. I am working on a simple homework datamining project. But I am fed up of writing DBManagers on my own. I am very well aware of Hibernate, but I am not using it here. So I was just curious about whether there are such tools or plugins or anything. I am using netbeans and MySQL.

thanks a lot.

Comment: What capabilities or features should have the `DBManager` class? What it is expecting to do?

Comment: I want the basic update, add and delete for operations for various combinations of a given POJO.

Answer (score 1):

If you need the typical operations related with typical POJOs that are already a link between the database and your business logic, what are you asking about is really near to an ORM. I understand that you have Java objects that matches records in your MySQL database and that is one of the key concepts of an ORM like Hibernate is.

Anyway if you are looking for a simple (and limited) library that provides some kind of tools like save, update or delete records from a database, you will find deprecated and abandoned projects like these:

- [DB Objects for Java](http://dbobjects.sourceforge.net/)
- [JStorm - Simple Tool for Object Relational Mapping](http://jstorm.sourceforge.net/)

By other hand if you prefer to test an easy and simple ORM, you can try [ActiveObjects](http://java.net/projects/activeobjects/pages/Home) who has a simple and functional approach.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without knowing what your `DBManager` class actually does!

Why don't you just write your `DBManager` in such a way that you can reuse it in other projects. That way you won't have to keep rewriting it...

Comment: This seems to be a good idea! Can you give me some tips on doing so? It will be appreciated.

Comment: As I said - I don't know what it is you want your `DBManager` class to do. You said you've already written some code for this a few times. Have a go at creating a version that would work it two of your cases. If you post some code I can give you some pointers.